# How to pass data from Partial view to post action method in mvc4?

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc-4

Hi i have one view called **Customer**.In that view  i have one field called **Area**. I kept one add button near to area. suppose if area is not in the list means i click that add button it open **AreaPartialView** as popup window.

Now i have one issue in that. That is the data is not passing  from partial view to post action method of controller.

**My Model**

```
    public Nullable<System.Guid> AreaID { get; set; }
    public string Area { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.Guid> CityID{ get; set; }
    public string  City { get; set; }
```

**My Controller**

```
    public ActionResult AreaPartialView()
   {
       ViewBag.CityID = new SelectList(db.Cities, "CityID", "DisplayName");
       return View("AreaPartialView");
   }
  [HttpPost]

   public ActionResult AddAreaInfo(CustomerViewModel objareaVM)
   {
        var objAreaID = Guid.NewGuid();
        ViewBag.CityID = new SelectList(db.Cities, "CityID", "DisplayName", objareaVM.CityID);

      var ObjArea = new Area()
        {
            AreaID =objAreaID,
            DisplayName = objareaVM.Area,
            PrintName = objareaVM.Area,
            CityID = objareaVM.CityID,
            IsActive = true,
            IsDeleted = false,
            CreatedDate = DateTime.Now,
            EditedDate = DateTime.Now,
            LastActiveOn = DateTime.Now,
            RowID = Guid.NewGuid(),
            CreatedSessionID = Guid.NewGuid(),
            EditedSessionID = Guid.NewGuid(),
            OfflineMode = false,
            OfflineID = Guid.NewGuid()
        };

        db.Areas.Add(ObjArea);
        db.SaveChanges();
        ModelState.Clear();

        return Json("Customer", JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

 }
```

**My View**

```
   <div id="Area">
   <div class="col-sm-4">
   <div class="form-group">
   @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Area, new { @class = "control-label"})
   @Html.DropDownList("AreaID", null, "Select", new { @class = "form-control required" })
   <button id="AddArea">Area</button>
   <div id="AddAreaNew"></div>
            </div>
          </div>
       </div>
```

**My j-query**

```
   <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2-ui.js"></script>
   <link rel="stylesheet"href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.2/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />

    <script type="text/javascript">
   $("#AddArea").click(function () {
       $('#AddAreaNew').dialog("open");
     });
  $(function () {
       $('#AddAreaNew').dialog({
           autoOpen: false,
           width: 400,
           height: 500,
           resizable: false,
           title: 'Add Area',
           modal: true,
           open: function (event, ui) {
               $(this).load("@Url.Action("AreaPartialView", "Customer")");
           },
           buttons: {
               "Close": function () {
                   $(this).dialog("close");
               }
           }
       });
   });
```

**My Partial View**

```
   @Html.Label("Area" , new { @class = "control-label" })
   @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Area, new { @class = "form-control", type = "text" ,id ="AreaName"})
   @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Area)


  @Html.Label("City")        
  @Html.DropDownList("CityID", null, "Select", new { @class = "form-control " })


  <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.4-ui.min.js"></script>
  <link href="~/Content/jquery-ui-1.10.4.custom.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.8.24.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
  function SaveArea() {
    var Area = $("#AreaName").val();
    var CityID = $("#CityID").val();
    alert(Area);
    var AreaAdd = {
        "AreaName": Area, "CityID": CityID
                };
    alert(AreaAdd.AreaName);
    alert(AreaAdd.CityID);

    $.post("/Customer/AddAreaInfo", AreaAdd,
    function (data) { if (data == 0) { location = location.href; } }, 'json').success(function (data) {

        alert("success");
        //window.close();
    });
 }
</script>
```

if i click the add button Area partial view will open as popup window and if i enter the details and click Create button it get  the values and showing all alert messages. But the problem is it does not pass the Area value to post action method  it pass the City ID value but it doesn't pass the **Area** value to post method. The Area value will be always null.

Please any one cross check my code and tell me the solution.

Advance Thanks...

Comment: use a ajax get and pass the Area value to the controller, return view based on Area value and  CityID

Comment: i used ajax too but  getting same issue

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with asp.net try this changes

```
 var AreaAdd = { Area: Area, CityID: CityID };
```

or use `FormCollection`

```
 public ActionResult AddAreaInfo(FormCollection objareaVM)
   {
        var objAreaID = Guid.NewGuid();
        ViewBag.CityID = new SelectList(db.Cities, "CityID", "DisplayName", objareaVM["CityID"]);

      var ObjArea = new Area()
        {
            AreaID =objAreaID,
            DisplayName = objareaVM["AreaName"],
            PrintName = objareaVM["AreaName"],
            CityID = objareaVM["CityID"],
            IsActive = true,
            IsDeleted = false,
            CreatedDate = DateTime.Now,
            EditedDate = DateTime.Now,
            LastActiveOn = DateTime.Now,
            RowID = Guid.NewGuid(),
            CreatedSessionID = Guid.NewGuid(),
            EditedSessionID = Guid.NewGuid(),
            OfflineMode = false,
            OfflineID = Guid.NewGuid()
        };

        db.Areas.Add(ObjArea);
        db.SaveChanges();
        ModelState.Clear();

        return Json("Customer", JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

 }
```

Comment: how its possible  madalin it will show error. Because  in that place we will refer the model right.

Comment: from what i can tell the javascript object that you pass to the controler (AreaAdd) is named objareaVM in asp.net corect me if i am wrong?

Comment: Madalin the flow is if the data is first pass to model and then only it will pass to controller . so we have to pass the model name in controller we cant pass the obj name which we given in the  j query, based on my knowledge this is correct in mvc4.

Comment: what are you doing with the ajax data `AreaAdd`?, why are you passing it if you are using data from the model?

Comment: First we getting the data in particular object  var Area = $("#AreaName").val();
    var CityID = $("#CityID").val(); then assign the two data in single object     var AreaAdd = {
        "AreaName": Area, "CityID": CityID
                }; then we pass this AreaAdd to post action method of controller  see that url

Comment: in the controller where do you reference that data,how do you get it,how do you process it??

Comment: see the below link. in this it contain basic flow of mvc http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/54576/Understanding-ASP-NET-MVC-Model-View-Controller-Ar

Comment: how do you get a value from a view in a controller?

Comment: simple madalin  first define the properties of each field in Model. Then we define the View . while defining the view it have to find the properties  of each field so it get the properties from the model.  see the view code. now  how it will get the data from view to controller so  we  have give the model name in controller. while Saving the data the data is passed to appropriate model and then model to controller.  see my model code my model name is CustomerViewModel. I called that in Controller public ActionResult AddAreaInfo(CustomerViewModel objareaVM).

Comment: post the CustomerViewModel

Comment: public Nullable<System.Guid> AreaID { get; set; }
    public string Area { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.Guid> CityID{ get; set; }
    public string  City { get; set; }  this is my model and this model name is Customer ViewMOdel

Comment: it already there then i suggest you to study some basic flow of  MVC  it is very easy . if you wamt any tutorials means let me know'

Comment: the second part is totally wrong it wont come as like that first part is correct but i already did that it getting the values in j query madalin but when i pass it to controller the Area value will be null

Comment: what does alert($("#AreaName").val()); output?

Comment: its getting the value from the Field Area the Area Field ID is AreaName

Answer (score 0):

See your Model class, you have "Area" Name of the Class Property.

```
public string Area { get; set; }
```

And you are posting Area with "AreaName", So its not correct

```
   var AreaAdd = {
    "AreaName": Area, "CityID": CityID
            };
```

Now Change Your Partial View Jquery Code :

```
    var AreaAdd = {
    "Area": Area, "CityID": CityID
            };
```

Comment: but i gave id as AreaName chirag

Comment: Ok now use : var AreaAdd = {
        "Area": AreaAdd.AreaName, "CityID": CityID
                };    It will work.

Comment: no chirag its is not working it didnt go for post action method

Comment: as per my code it getting the values  in   var AreaAdd = {
    "AreaName": Area, "CityID": CityID
            };  it shows the alert message . but it not pass the value controller . it pass the city id but it not pass the area value this is my issue

Comment: please try this ('):  var AreaAdd = { "AreaName": ''+Area+'', "CityID": CityID};

Comment: chirag this code getting the values chirag it shows the alert messages to but when i pass this value to controller the Area will be null but not city id please tell me the  solution to pass the area value which we got to controller :( :(

Comment: Please do just copy and past :  var AreaAdd = { "Area": ''+Area+'', "CityID": CityID};    Please Replace AreaName with Area, Because in your model you have used "Area" as string, so you to pass same name as you mentioned in model.

Comment: no chirag its no worlking i tried many ways but no use the coding is correct but i donno y its not working

Comment: Ya sure wait i wil post

Comment: function SaveArea() {
        var Area = $("#AreaName").val();
        var CityID = $("#CityID").val();
        alert(Area);                                                                                   var AreaAdd = { "AreaName": '' + Area + '', "CityID": CityID };                           alert(AreaAdd.AreaName);
        alert(AreaAdd.CityID);

        $.post("/Customer/AddAreaInfo", AreaAdd,
        function (data) { if (data == 0) { location = location.href; } }, 'json').success(function (data) {
            alert("sucess");
               });
    }
    </script>

Answer (score 0):

This will do the trick for you:

```
var AreaAdd = {Area:"your area", CityID:"your city id"};
```

Actually in mvc the names should be exactly same as the name of model properties.

Comment: kayani it totally change the output i gave same as like you mentioned it pass the value of area as AreaName (my AreaField ID name) and CityID for city field

Comment: well its pretty self explanatory you can modify it to fit your needs